# CSS3 - Opacity transition is not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change a `div opacity` depending on having the `class active` or not.

When the `div` has the `active` class, I want to change the `opacity to 1`. If the `div` does not have the `active` class, I want to change the `opacity to 0`.

Follows my CSS code:

```
.high-light{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
    opacity:0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 3s linear;
}

#multicanvasArea.active .high-light { 
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

Thank you

**[EDIT]**

One of the problems was that I change the css property to "block" and "none". The other was solve by the answer choosen.

Comment: where your html code ?

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I will edit the post to put the html code as soon as possible. Thank you

Comment: add your jsfidlle /snippet of code.

Comment: offtopic: why have different transition properties for prefixed properties? (`0.4s` instead of `5s` and different timing-function)

Comment: @LuudJacobs no reason. It is different because is a test css, not the definitive one. Want I want first is the transition works and then I will take care about the times and other stuffs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the div has the active class, I want to change the opacity to 1. If the div does not have the active class, I want to change the opacity to 0.

You need to combine the classes like so.

As it was you have `.highlight` as a **child** of `.active`.

```
.high-light{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
    opacity:0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 3s linear;
}

.high-light.active { 
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not the transition, it's the height 100% which is not taking effect because the parent element (body) is not tall 100%.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#multicanvasArea").toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.high-light{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    transition: opacity 3s linear;
}

#multicanvasArea.active .high-light { 
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multicanvasArea">
  <p class="high-light">Highlight</p>
  <p class="">Other text</p>
</div>
<button>Toggle class</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code was 95% there, just a few tweaks I made seem to do the trick. Here is the new css:

```
#multicanvasArea .high-light{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
    opacity:0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 3s linear;
}

#multicanvasArea.active .high-light { 
    opacity:1;
}
```

Here is a link to a pen with a working example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEjrJo

Answer (score 0):

this is a working example. The Javascript is only to toggle the class.

```
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s linear;
  &.active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/RZRygZieCUMVWiOVEJR8?p=preview